# Reversing digits in Java. Leading and trailing zeros won't print

Tags: java, reversing

The problem was to reverse user entered digits. I have it working but while testing it I realized that it won't print either leading or trailing zeros.

For example if I enter 10 it only displays 1 in the result.

If I enter 0110 I get a result of 11.

Here is my code:

```
public class ReversingDigits {

int value;
int reverse;

public ReversingDigits() {
    value = 10;
    reverse = 0;
}// end constructor

public void reverse() {
    System.out.println("Enter a valid 2-4 digit number: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    value = input.nextInt();
    if (value < 10 || value > 9999){
        System.out.print("Please enter a valid 2-4 digit number: ");
       value = input.nextInt();
    }

    while (value > 0) {
        reverse *= 10;
        reverse += value % 10;
        value /= 10;

    }
    System.out.println("Reversed numbers are: " + reverse);

}

}//end class
```

Any ideas on how to get the zeros to print?

Thanks

Comment: that is because you are using int primitive and 01 is always 1. Try using string instead

Comment: Reverse the `String` not the number.  I bet if you printed `value` before you tried reversing it, it would be `11`

Comment: If you reverse it as a string it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you work with a String while reversing your number. It will preserve leading zeros. As you know 00001 is the same as 1 when in `int` representation, and so converting that to a string will remove all leading zeros.

Here's your code sample modified to read a string from the input, and only convert it to an int when you need to check the range.

```
public void reverse() {
    System.out.println("Enter a valid 2-4 digit number: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String value = input.next();
    int valueInt = Integer.parseInt(value);

    if (valueInt < 10 || valueInt > 9999){
        System.out.print("Please enter a valid 2-4 digit number: ")
        value = input.next();
    }

    String valueReversed = new StringBuilder(value).reverse().toString();

    System.out.println("Reversed numbers are: " + valueReversed);

}
```

Note that in your code, if a user enters the wrong range twice in a row, your program won't prompt him again. You may want to put this part of the code into a `do-while` loop which only exits when the input range is correct. Example

```
do {
    System.out.print("Please enter a valid 2-4 digit number: ")
    value = input.next();
    int valueInt = Integer.parseInt(value);
} while (valueInt < 10 || valueInt > 9999);
//only get here when inputted value finally within target range.
```

**Edit:** As mentioned by @Levenal, you may also want to wrap `Integer.parseInt` in a `try/catch` block for `NumberFormatException` in the event the user passes in a non-numerical input.

Comment: Worth noting that if you call parseInt on a non-numerical char a NumberFormatException will be thrown

Comment: Thanks...I've learned something new! That is the first time I have used StringBuider!

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, reversing numbers you are much better off reversing a string.  If you are allowed to stray away from console input, JOptionPane is quite good for simple String input, like so:

```
    while(true){
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please anter a number between 10 & 9999: ");
        if(input == null){//If input cancelled
            break; //Exit loop
        } else if(input.matches("\\d{2,4}")){//Regex for at least 2 but no more than 4 numbers
            System.out.println(new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString());//Reverse
            break;
        }
    }
```

Good luck!